# How to display string variables in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI program in python to generate random Lottery numbers. I want to have a menu bar for choosing Powerball or MegaMillion. And after choosing it, there will be buttons to let user select how many tickets to show. But I cannot make the method work. I want to show different lines of number lists when I click the button, but it does show anything. I'm not finished yet since it doesn't work. I am new to Python and programming, please help! Thank you !

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class lotteryNum:
    def __init__(self):
        window=Tk()
        window.title("Lottery Number Generator")

        menubar = Menu(window)
        window.config(menu=menubar)

        self.pbLst = [x for x in range(1,70)]
        self.pbLst2=[x for x in range(1,27)]
        self.mmLst = [x for x in range(1,76)]
        self.mmLst2=[x for x in range(1,16)]
        self.usingLst=["*"]*6



        #Type Menu
        typeMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Which Lottery", menu = typeMenu)
        typeMenu.add_command(label="Powerball", command= self.powerBall)
        typeMenu.add_command(label="Mega Milion", command= self.megaMillion)


        #Exit menu
        exitmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Exit", menu = exitmenu)
        exitmenu.add_command(label = "Quit", command = window.quit)

        #Welcome label
        Label(window, text="Welcome to Lottery Generator!").pack()

        frame=Frame(window)
        frame.pack()

        #Text Label
        self.showResults = StringVar()
        Label(frame, text=self.showResults).pack()




        Button(window, text="$2", command=self.runLottery()).pack(side=LEFT)

        window.mainloop()


    def powerBall(self):
        # random.shuffle(self.pbLst)
        # random.shuffle(self.pbLst2)
        self.usingLst=self.pbLst
        self.usingLst2=self.pbLst2

    def megaMillion(self):
        # random.shuffle(self.mmLst)
        # random.shuffle(self.mmLst2)
        self.usingLst=self.mmLst
        self.usingLst2=self.mmLst2

    def runLottery(self):
        random.shuffle(self.usingLst)
        random.shuffle(self.usingLst2)
        self.usingLst[:5].extend(self.usingLst2[0])
        self.showResults.set(self.usingLst)





lotteryNum()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should work if you change this line:

```
Label(frame, text=self.showResults).pack()
```

to this:

```
Label(frame, textvariable=self.showResults).pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Finished code just let whoever interested know what I'm try to do here.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class lotteryNum:
    def __init__(self):
        window=Tk()
        window.title("Lottery Number Generator")

        menubar = Menu(window)
        window.config(menu=menubar)

        self.pbLst = [x for x in range(1,70)]
        self.pbLst2=[x for x in range(1,27)]
        self.mmLst = [x for x in range(1,76)]
        self.mmLst2=[x for x in range(1,16)]
        self.usingLst=[0]*6
        self.usingLst2=[0]*6

        #Type Menu
        typeMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Which Lottery", menu = typeMenu)
        typeMenu.add_command(label="Powerball", command= self.powerBall)
        typeMenu.add_command(label="Mega Milion", command= self.megaMillion)


        #Exit menu
        exitmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Exit", menu = exitmenu)
        exitmenu.add_command(label = "Quit", command = window.quit)

        #Welcome label
        Label(window, text="Welcome to Lottery Generator!").pack()

        frame=Frame(window)
        frame.pack()

        #Text Label to show numbers
        self.showResults = StringVar()
        self.showResults5=StringVar()
        oneTicket=Label(frame, textvariable=self.showResults).pack()
        fiveTicket=Message(frame,textvariable=self.showResults5).pack()

        #Buttons to generate tickets
        Button(window, text="one ticket", command=self.showTicket).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(window, text="five tickets", command=self.showTicket5).pack(side=LEFT)

        #Button to draw the tickets
        Button(window, text="Draw tickets", command=self.drawTickets).pack()

        #The process to draw each ticket
        self.covered=False





        window.mainloop()


    def powerBall(self):
        self.usingLst=self.pbLst
        self.usingLst2=self.pbLst2
        self.runLottery()
        self.winingNumbers = self.showLst

    def megaMillion(self):
        self.usingLst=self.mmLst
        self.usingLst2=self.mmLst2
        self.runLottery()
        self.winingNumbers = self.showLst

    def runLottery(self):
        random.shuffle(self.usingLst)
        random.shuffle(self.usingLst2)
        self.showLst=self.usingLst[:5]
        self.showLst.sort()
        self.showLst.append(self.usingLst2[0])

    def showTicket(self):
        self.runLottery()
        if (self.showLst==self.winingNumbers):
            self.covered = True
        self.carry1=""
        for i in range(6):
            self.carry1+=str(self.showLst[i])+"  "
        self.showResults.set(self.carry1)

    def showTicket5(self):
        self.showTicket()
        self.carry5=""
        for i in range(4):
            self.runLottery()
            if(self.showLst==self.winingNumbers):
                self.covered=True
            for k in range(6):
                self.carry5+=str(self.showLst[k])+"  "
            self.carry5+="\n"
        self.showResults5.set(self.carry5)

    def drawTickets(self):
        top=Toplevel()
        top.title("Draw Result")
        label1=Label(top, text="The wining numbers are ").pack()
        var1=StringVar()
        label2 = Label(top, textvariable=var1).pack()
        var1.set(self.winingNumbers)
        var2=StringVar()
        Label3 = Label(top, textvariable=var2).pack()
        if (self.covered==True):
            var2.set("You Win!!")
        else:
            var2.set("You Lose!!")


lotteryNum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Print self.usingLst to make sure it contains something, and

```
self.showResults=Label(frame, text="no choices made")
self.showResults.pack()
```

then in runLottery

```
self.showResults["text"]="\n".join(self.usingLst)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tired a different way and it works. I will post the answer below